# Awareness API - Place type home

Tags: android, google-api, google-awareness

On google awareness API Guides page there is mention about Context types.

> Contextual data includes sensor-derived data such as location
>   (lat/lng), place (home, work, coffee shop)

However, on reference page with Places type [Place reference](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/Place), there is no mention about Home type. Is there a way to find out if user is at home (of course if he has it set up in his google settings)?

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party, but now that Google's Awareness API has deprecated Places, you can use the [NumberEight SDK](https://www.numbereight.me/our-tech) as an alternative. One bonus is that it works on iOS too.

It performs a wide variety of context recognition tasks including:

- Real-time physical activity detection
- Current place categories (including Work and Home, which can trigger even without GPS)
- Motion detection
- Reachability
- Local weather

It can also record user context for reports and analysis via the online portal.

To quickly check when a user is at home in Kotlin, you would write:

```
val ne = NumberEight()

ne.onPlaceUpdated { glimpse ->
    val place = glimpse.mostProbable

    if (place.context.home == Knowledge.AtPlaceContext) {
        Log.d("MyApp", "User is at home!")
    }
}
```

Here are some [iOS](https://gitlab.com/numbereight/iOSExample) and [Android](https://gitlab.com/numbereight/AndroidExample) example projects.

*Disclosure: I'm one of the developers.*